# cytoscape.js cose layout nodes overlapping

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to determine how to get correct spacing when using the cytoscape.js library with the cose layout.  In particular, when I define a width and height of a node, the nodes tend to overlap.

Here is the **[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/XLfeXrD08PkhX0AjsUJV/)**

I've tried to experiment with the layout options, but I haven't found any options that provide me with my intended result.  Also ideally, I'd be able to have nodes of varying sizes.

A side note:  An odd behavior I've found, when creating the graph with an edge that has the same source and target.. the layout spacing is as I would have intended. (see the red button on the plnkr).  But obviously doesn't help if I don't have this type of edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding edges changes the dynamics of the system.  The basic forces are spring/elasticity, repulsion, and to-centre gravity.  You also may be interested in the node overlap multiplier, which helps increase forces when overlap is detected.  You have to experiment with many combinations to see what works with your data, but it does work.  Here are some examples where the options were tuned appropriately to the data: [#1](http://genemania.org/#/search/human/p53) [#2](http://genemania.org/#/search/human/p53%7Crfwd2%7Cdet1%7Cmdm2%7Cmdm4%7Cmyb%7Cetv4%7Cddb1%7Cdlg1%7Cakap5%7Cnlk)

It's a trade-off of developer time to user-facing runtime performance.  CoSE is really fast, but the developer needs to set the options just right for their data.  Other force layouts, like CoSE-Bilkent and Cola, are much easier for the dev to use -- but they run slower.