# Cytoscape - graph entire screen

Tags: javascript, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js

i need to render graphs and i want to use cytoscape (plotly dash cytoscape).
Because with the plotly dash wrapper it is possible to write everything in python and i don't need to split my (small) application into a backend and a frontend part.

I want that the graph uses the entire screen and orders the nodes in a good and readable way.
Unfortunately i don't find a description of all possible parameters in the api documentation.

Instead of the rendering in [image: this] picture i would like to have it in [image: this]way.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
The graph has the entire space available, i can move it with my mouse everwhere i want.

These are my current properties:

```
cyto.Cytoscape(
id='knowledge-graph',
layout={
    'name': 'cose',
    'idealEdgeLength': 1000,
    'nodeOverlap': 500,
    'refresh': 20,
    'fit': True,
    'padding': 30,
    'randomize': False,
    'componentSpacing': 1000,
    'nodeRepulsion': 400000,
    'nestingFactor': 5,
    'gravity': 800,
    'numIter': 1000,
    'initialTemp': 200,
    'coolingFactor': 0.95,
    'minTemp': 1.0
},
style={
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "calc(100vh - 150px)",
},
stylesheet=[
    {'selector': 'edge', 'style': {'label': 'data(label)', 'curve-style': 'haystack',
                                   'haystack-radius': 0,
                                   'width': 5,
                                   'opacity': 0.5,
                                   'line-color': '#a8eae5'}, 'text-wrap': 'wrap'},
    {'selector': 'node', 'style': {'label': 'data(label)', 'background-color': '#30c9bc'}, 'text-wrap': 'wrap'},
]
```

)

Thank you!

Comment: Which layout is this? Adding the settings you use for rendering the current graph might help

Comment: i added the properties. Basically it is the cose layout from the demo page (and i played around with some properties)

Comment: In case you didn't find it already, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170772/cytoscape-js-cose-layout-nodes-overlapping) might be of interest

Comment: So basically i have to play around with these parameters to see what works for my data? Is there a documention for this parameters? Do you have an idea how to center the graph at the initial rendering?

Comment: Playing around with the parameters is not the most directly helpful and pleasant advice, I totally understand. But there was also this part "*Other force layouts, like CoSE-Bilkent and Cola, are much easier for the dev to use"* which I thought might be an option. I don't know a setting for initial centering but it should be possible to achieve by calling `cy.center()` directly after initialization. I guess you already found [this list](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cose) which covers all possible options, unfortunately missing a detailed description

Comment: you can try other layouts. There are some layout extensions such as fcose. I don't know how to inject extensions with python. Also if you increase `idealEdgeLength` and `nodeRepulsion` I expect to see the graph in a greater space

Comment: Do you know how to call cy.center() using the python wrapper for cytoscape?
Now i added the cose-bilkent layout with some parameters and it is better than before. 
But it is really slow with some big graphs (more than thousand edges)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [cytoscape-spread](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-spread) layout which first applies a force-directed layout for initial positions and then uses voronoi-based method to spread the nodes in the remaining space. You can check its demos [here](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-spread/) and [here](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-spread/demo-proteins.html).

Comment: Thanks, i tried to use the spread-layout. Unfortunately, the graph disappears after the animations and the layout is very slow for me. The cose-bilkent layout looks better on me. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then you can also try cytoscape-fcose which is the faster version of the cose-bilkent. It also introduces additional features over cose-bilkent such as component packing and layout constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't find a way to use fcose with the plotly dash cytoscape wrapper...